# How to delete all pixel layers in Photoshop

Tags: layers, images, photoshop-scripting, selections, actions

I have designed a website template in Photoshop CC2014 and after making this I have to upload it on a server for my client, but before this I want to delete all images (pixel layers) from .psd files. There are 80+ PSDs so can anyone help me in deleting **image (pixel layers)** from PSDs, **Excluding Background Layer**?

This would be great if you can give me **action or script**.

I know doing pixel filter can help but this is a very slow process.

[image: Layers I need to delete]

Comment: Just the be clear, you want to delete *all* normal pixel layers (anything that isn't a shape, color, adjustment, background etc)?

Comment: Yes you're right. I just wanted to delete **All Normal Pixel Layers**.

Comment: Isn't the "grid" layer a normal layer too?

Comment: Yes Mistakenly  forgot to highlight.

Comment: Ok no problem, just making sure. Should be easy enough to script

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you? did you mean my scripting skills?? if yes then I don't know about doing scripting that's why I ask to get script or Help from here.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the Layers panel filter cannot be recorded. Also, looping through all layers in Photoshop with a script is far from ideal.

Comment: Agreed @Joonas . I have tried to Record this process as action. but yes Photoshop doesn't support recording of filter panel. :(

Comment: I wrote a quick script but removing the layers in a loop is acting strange... Is hiding or clearing the layers acceptable?

Comment: I think you're almost there. how about if you clear (Images) and leave pixel layer empty then add another code to DELETE empty layers.

Comment: @Cai, did you manage to clear pixel layers??? if yes then this code might help you in removing **empty layers**

[link](https://github.com/LeZuse/photoshop-scripts/blob/master/default/Delete%20All%20Empty%20Layers.jsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will loop through all your layers and groups and delete any normal (pixel) layers. It will record the deletions in the history (as a single history state, thanks Joonas) but *PLEASE* save before using this and test it thoroughly as I've only done limited testing.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.suspendHistory("Remove Normal Layers", "deletePixelLayers( doc )");

function deletePixelLayers(target)
{
    try{
        var layers = target.layers;
        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++)
        {
            var curLayer = layers[i];
            var visible = curLayer.visible; // remember visibility
            curLayer.allLocked = false; // unlock layer

            // Layer is a group
            if ("LayerSet" == curLayer.typename) {
                deletePixelLayers(curLayer);
            }

            // Layer is a NORMAL (Pixel) Layers
            if (LayerKind.NORMAL == curLayer.kind
                && !curLayer.isBackgroundLayer) {

                curLayer.remove(); // Delete the layer
                --i;
            };

            // restore layer visibility
            if (curLayer) curLayer.visible = visible;
        };
    }catch(e){
        ; // do nothing
    }
};
deletePixelLayers(doc);
```

Comment: Since you already wrapped it in a function and all, it's pretty easy to use `sustendHistory` to write only one history state. [Like this](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/d3c8e4273271433bf2f90835bf65c172). I didn't edit it in the answer cause I can't test it right now.

Comment: Good point @Joonas edited it in, works fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but its not working.

Error: **The Command "Delete" is not currently available.**

Comment: Do you have locked layers or hidden layers? That may be it, I'm not sure

Comment: Yes few layer are hidden. does this affect the code?

Comment: updated to unlock layers, try now (locked layers didn't give me that error but they do stop the script)

Comment: Wow You did fantastic work. but on completion of script why my all hidden layer turn on?? is it a part of code?

Comment: Updated it to remember the layer visibility, no idea why it was changing that

Comment: anyway you did great work. You deserve 5 stars. Thanks

Comment: No problem @Ali glad to help